# Find the nearest positions

Tags: matlab

On each day, I have 10000 position pairs in the form of (x,y); Up to now, I have collected 30 days. I want to select a position pair from each day so that all the positions pairs have similar coordinates (x,y) value. By similar I mean the euclidean distance is minimized between any two pairs. How to do it in matlab with efficiency. Because with brute force, it is almost impossible.

In brute force case, we have 10000^30 possibilities, each operation say needs 10^-9 second,
It will run forever.

Comment: The problem complexity (number of operations) seems very high, and I'm not sure that can be avoided. Anyway, what do you mean by "the Euclidean distance is minimized between any two pairs"? You can't minimize all distances _simultaneously_; you need to minimize a _single_ metric: Sum of distances? Maximum distance over all pairs? Sum of squared distances?

Comment: It would be nice to get some clarification on the requirements. Are you looking for just one point from each day's data? Are you looking to map every point from day X to a unique point from day X+1? Do the points have a one-to-one mapping or are they unrelated? What about the distance metric as mentioned by @LuisMendo? This *could* be simply a shortest-path problem with O(V^2) complexity. Or it *could* be really nasty.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use the k-means algorithm or one of its variations. it is relatively easy to implement (it is also part of the Statistics Toolbox) and has a runtime about O(nkl).

Comment: Very nice, knnsearch should be the most convenient way to get it done.

Comment: Yes, the problem is can we construct such large matrix. Basically it works in the limit of java to my best knowledge.

Comment: You can check this using 'memory'. Depending on the machine you are working on there are several options to get a maximum space available.
This article about big data in MATLAB might help http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/big-data-matlab.html

Answer (score 1):

Analysing all the possibilities will give you for sure the best result you are looking for.
If you want an approximate result you can consider the first two days and analyse all the possibilities for these 2 days and pick the best result. Then when analyse the next day keep the result obtained previously and find the point of the third column closest to the previous two.
In this way you will obtain an approximate solution but with a less computational complexity.

Comment: Thanks, I need a globally optimized solution. That is the requirement.